# How can I clean open with on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

How can I remove an item from the open with context menu in windows 10? For example, I want to remove path **"D:\atom-windows\Atom\atom.exe" "%1"**: because atom is no longer installed on D:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Context menu items are typically registry keys. You could a) find the key, or b) use something like ccleaner to purge your registry of dead keys.

Comment: I tried https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18119/remove-programs-from-open-with-menu-in-explorer/ but nothing change.

Comment: Go to `HKCR\.json` in registry and post the registry keys in your question.

Comment: This is picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8thvc.png @biswa

Comment: You do understand that Visual Studio Code is based on Atom right?

Comment: @Ramhound I think it isn't issued for this problems

Comment: Well your screenshot doesn't even list Atom in the open with menu, so your problem, isn't clear.  Your registry setting for that extension isn't linked to Atom either.  If you want to remove, `D:\atom-windows\Atom\atom.exe` from your open with menu, find all instance of it in the registry and delete the corresponding registry key.

Comment: I will try to use `Find` in the registry and delete the corresponding registry key.

Comment: I removed everything related to `atom.exe` in the registry after I restarted my PC. BTW, I found `atom.exe` in Applications and removed it, it like `Code.exe`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzowe.png. But the problem still exists.

Comment: Are you trying to get get of Visual Studio Code or Atom, because in every screenshot you have provided, only Visual Studio Code is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) and run `Scan for Issues` in `Registry` of [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) to fix all issues. Now that path was removed: [Open With after running CCleaner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3o4N.png).
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Back up registry before any change. If any problem happens after changing, you can restore to undo the change.

**How to back up and restore the registry in Windows:**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows

On Windows 10, open Run, type “regedit.exe” to open Registry Editor, open below location:
***HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts***

Sub entries of FileExts are all file extensions, find specific file extension which has the item(open with context menu) you want to delete, click sub entry “OpenWithList”, on the right side bar, check “Data” column, you can delete corresponding item.